# Adding tolerations to fluentbit pod and making it persistent

Tags: kubernetes, fluent-bit

I am using fluentbit as a pod deployment where I am creating many fluentbit pods which are attached to azure blob containers. Since multiple pods exist I tried adding tolerations as I did on daemonset deployment but it did not work and failed. Also every time I delete and start the pods reinvests all the the again. Please advise on fixing these issues.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: deployment 
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: config_map_name
      configMap:
        name: config_map_name
    - name: pvc_name
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pvc_name       
  containers:
    - name: fluentbit-logger
      image: fluent/fluent-bit:2.1.3
      env:
        - name: FLUENTBIT_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: fluentbit-secret
              key: user
        - name: FLUENTBIT_PWD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: fluentbit-secret
              key: pwd              
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: "32Mi"
          cpu: "50m"
        limits:
          memory: "64Mi"
          cpu: "100m"
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
        privileged: true
      volumeMounts:
        - name: config_map_name
          mountPath: "/fluent-bit/etc"
        - name: pvc_name
          mountPath: mount_path  
      tolerations: 
      - key: "dedicated"
        operator: "Equal"
        value: "sgelk"
        effect: "NoSchedule"

      - key: "dedicated"
        operator: "Equal"
        value: "kafka"
        effect: "NoSchedule"
```

Getting the error as below

```
error: error validating "/tmp/fluentbit-deploy.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Pod.spec.containers[0]): unknown field "tolerations" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tolerations` attribute needs to be set on the pod, but you are attempting to set it on a container (that's why you see the error "unknown field "tolerations" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container"). You would need to write:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: deployment
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: config_map_name
      configMap:
        name: config_map_name
    - name: pvc_name
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pvc_name
  containers:
    - name: fluentbit-logger
      image: fluent/fluent-bit:2.1.3
      env:
        - name: FLUENTBIT_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: fluentbit-secret
              key: user
        - name: FLUENTBIT_PWD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: fluentbit-secret
              key: pwd
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: "32Mi"
          cpu: "50m"
        limits:
          memory: "64Mi"
          cpu: "100m"
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
        privileged: true
      volumeMounts:
        - name: config_map_name
          mountPath: "/fluent-bit/etc"
        - name: pvc_name
          mountPath: mount_path
  tolerations:
  - key: "dedicated"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "sgelk"
    effect: "NoSchedule"

  - key: "dedicated"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "kafka"
    effect: "NoSchedule"
```

Comment: Tried it now getting a different error `error: error parsing /tmp/fluentbit-deploy.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 41: did not find expected '-' indicator
`

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that problem. If I copy and paste the manifest shown in this answer and replace `config_map_name` and `pvc_name` with valid values, this manifest applies without errors. It sounds like you may have introduced a formatting problem.

Comment: okay my bad I needed to indent it in one more level. One more thing Every time I delete and start fluentbit it reindexes the entire data any idea where to add the configuration to keep a checkpoint of data ingested

Comment: That seems like a different question (so you should open a new question on this site).

Comment: okay will do it.